# Installing development version of a module in python

Tags: python, owlready

I am trying to install the development version of owlready2; I take the following step;

1. Extracted the development version downloaded from https://bitbucket.org/jibalamy/owlready2/downloads/
2. uninstalled previously installed owlready versions
3. went to the extracted directory and did python setup.py develop

but it is giving me the error that No module named owlready2

The code I am trying to run is below;

```
from owlready2 import * 
onto = get_ontology("http://myplatform.com/test_sensor_onto") 
onto.imported_ontologies = [] 
sosa = get_ontology("file://sosa.owl").load() 
ssn = get_ontology("file://ssn.owl").load() 
onto.imported_ontologies.append(sosa) 
onto.imported_ontologies.append(ssn) 
sensor = sosa.Sensor("mySensor", namespace = onto) 
onto.save("test_sensor_onto2.owl")
```

I have also tried to use python setup.py install, but then it gives an error that

sensor =sosa.Sensor("mySensor", namespace = onto) 
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

This error is same as for non-development versions of owlready2. I am wondering if I am doing anything wrong while installing the development version or I have to change some settings somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at your site packages directories with `python -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages())"`. Make sure a valid link was created in one of those directories for your package.

You might also try using `pip -e` ([editable installs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs)) as an alternative. This is similar to [setuptools develop mode](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#development-mode). `sudo pip install -e /my/package/path`. Using `pip` will install any dependencies required by the package.

`setup.py` may also require `sudo` to update the site-wide package directory. Add `-v` for verbose output: `sudo python setup.py -v develop`

Comment: by doing python -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages())" I found out ['/Users/../anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages']. When I navigated through this directory, I can see "Owlready2.egg-link" file in there. Also, doing your other 2 recommended method sdid not solve the problem. Any further ideas?